# Squeezing the Term of a Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I understand what squeezing the term theorem means, but when trying to prove the theorem, I am totally lost.

It begins with giving me:

$L \leq S_n \leq T_n$ (which I understand),

but it implies $|S_n-L| \leq |T_n-L|$ which I cannot figure out how to prove.  I believe I will use the triangle inequality, but I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$L\le Sn\le Tn$$
$$L-L\le Sn-L\le Tn-L$$
$$0\le Sn-L\le Tn-L$$
$$|Sn-L|\le |Tn-L|$$

Comment: So I can just add the absolute value signs at the end?

Comment: This is because both of them are non-negative, $|Sn-L|=Sn-L$ and similar for the $Tn$.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your input!